# print or set to variable - Hash key and field(value) - from redis database using python

Tags: python, hash, redis, key, field

Trying to read a hash key and field from redis Database using python.  In the DB i have many numeric keys(0,1,2,etc), and each has a TIMESTAMP field with the time value (2021-08-07 11:28:07.330731)

I can read the hash key and also read the desired field, individually.

How do I get it to read\list and print out to either screen or a variable the hash key associated with the desired field value.

r = myRedis database

field = r.hget('0','TIMESTAMP') # this gives me the field "TIMESTAMP" value, from Hash with key '0'
and
intkeylist = r.keys() # gives me the key list

just not sure how to tie these two together, so I get all my keys associated with the fields "TIMESTAMP"(value) listed together

Desired OUTPUT:
Key Field value

[image]

etc...

Comment: Fix your formatting first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timestamps_log = ""    
for x in intkeylist:
       timestamps_log += str(x + r.hget(x,'TIMESTAMP'))
print(timestamps_log)
```

Comment: Ty, this works.  Thought there would be a redis command for this.

Comment: @dancer Right, fixed.

Comment: and to dump to variable i would put?
for x in intkeylist:
       keylist_timestamp = (x,r.get(x,'TIMESTAMP'))

Comment: @dancer like that